# How do I get my React TextField to open the number pad when inputting on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, mobile, textfield

I have a React TextField that is taking user input and it is representing a date. When the user clicks on the field I want the number keyboard to open instead of the full alphabet. I was looking at the React docs [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/) and trying to mimic their example.

My TextField looks like the following:

```
  <TextField
    { ...materialConfiguration }
    floatingLabelFixed={value.length > 0}
    floatingLabelText={label}
    errorText={errorText}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onKeyUp={this.debouncedOnKeyUp}
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
    type="number"
    label="Number"
    id="standard-number"
    >
    <Cleave value={value} options={{date: true, datePattern: ['m', 'd', 'Y']}} />
  </TextField>
```

I added the `type` `label` and `id` fields from the React example thinking that was what made the keyboard change but it does not work. How can I get this input to open the number pad?

The React example is this:

```
<TextField
  id="standard-number"
  label="Number"
  value={this.state.age}
  onChange={this.handleChange('age')}
  type="number"
  className={classes.textField}
  InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
  }}
  margin="normal"
/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATED in 2021**

```
  <TextField id="quantity" label="Quantity" inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric' }}/>
```

using `inputProps` does solve the issue. `inputProps` object is attributes applied to the input element.

https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api

Answer (score 10):

Yo have to add this attributes to your input tag:

```
<input type='number' inputMode='numeric' pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

Comment: But I don't have an input tag, this is a TextField

Comment: Your TextField is a custom component or a library?  if is custom pass the props to the children component, if is a library, try to add them to the TextField

Comment: it is the Material-UI TextField. I just tried adding the `type` `inoputMode` and `pattern` attributes to my TextField directly but that did not work either

Comment: Searching for a solution using material-ui textfield as well. The solution provided doesn't work. When I tap into the text field, the keyboard shows up with the numbers already, however all other symbols are there too, brackets, etc. It's not specifically the numberpad keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Real world example - noting that inputProps and InputProps are not the same somehow.

```js
<TextField
    inputProps={{
        inputMode: 'decimal',
    }}
    InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
                <Icon />
            </InputAdornment>
        ),
        endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton
                    disabled={disabled}
                    onClick={() => {
                        swapCurrencies()
                    }}
                >
                    <SwapVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
        ),
    }}
    name={'amount'}
    className={classes.root}
    fullWidth
    disabled={disabled}
    onChange={e => {
        doStuff()
    }} />
```

Answer (score 3):

Useful to know as well, if you want a decimal point to appear.
You will need to add the following to you input tag...

```
inputMode='decimal'
```

Example below

```
<input 
   type='number' 
   step='any' 
   inputMode='decimal' 
   pattern='\d*'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
     
 export default function NumericField(props) { 
    const [state,setState] = React.useState(""); 
    const handleChange=(event)=> {
    const regx = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
      if (event.target.value === '' || regx.test(event.target.value)) {
         setState( event.target.value);
  }

}
 return (
        <TextField 
            type="text"
            value={state}
            label={props.label} 
            fullWidth={props.fullWidth}
            onChange={handleChange} 
            id={props.id}
            required={props.required}
            disabled={props.disabled}
            error={props.error}
            helperText={props.helperText}
            name={props.name}/>
      
        );
    }
```